# Within a regex is \xhh same as \x{hh}?

Tags: php, regex, escaping

Within a regex seems that it is the same:

```
if(preg_match('/\x{61}/',"a",$m)) //Same as just \x61
    print_r($m);
```

But if you make echo both apart.

```
echo "\x61";//Display a
echo "\x{61}";//Display \x{61}
```

Note: Not confuse with the `'/\x{0000}/u'`

I don't see info about that and I'm not sure which to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pcre has its own escape rules, which are different from those in php. From http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt

> Characters whose value is less than 256 can be defined by either of the
>          two  syntaxes  for  \x. There is no difference in the way they are han-
>          dled. For example, \xdc is exactly the same as \x{dc}.